# proof - GCD and Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I have been trying to solve these but have had no success. Please help by **giving hints** not answers.

[image: None]

> Assuming that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ prove the following:
>   (a) $\gcd(a+b,a-b)=1$ or $2$. [*Hint:* Let $d=\gcd(a+b,a-b)$ and show that $d\mid 2a$, $d\mid 2b$; thus $d\le \gcd(2a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b)$]
>   (b) $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)=1$ or $3$.
>   (c) $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)=1$ or $2$. [*Hint:* $a^2+b^2=(a+b)(a-b)+2b^2$.]
>   (d) $\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)=1$ or $3$. [*Hint:* $a^2-ab+b^2=(a+b)^2-3ab$]

Source: Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton

Comment: What is the question? it seems like you forgot to upload it...

Comment: It is difficult to give hints, not answers, since the supplied hints are close to what one might have given. But for Question (b), note that if $d$ divides both then $d$ divides $2(2a+b)-(a+2b)$, that is, $d$ divides $3a$. Similarly, $d$ divides $3b$.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?). It is also good to add the source of the question.

Comment: BTW if you search a bit, you will find out that many of these questions have already been asked and answered on this site. The first one is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457296/prove-that-if-a-and-b-are-relatively-prime-then-gcdab-a-b-1-or-2

Comment: The main tool you will need to use is this: you can add any multiple of one number to the other number and the greatest common divisor won't change. In other words, $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b+ka)$ for any integer $k$. (Do you know why this tool is true?)

Comment: The thrid one can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153125/prove-gcdab-a2b2-is-1-or-2-if-gcda-b-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307545/how-can-i-find-the-possible-values-that-gcdab-a2b2-can-take-if-gcda

Comment: For (4) see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257392/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdab-a2-abb2-1-or-3 and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222967/let-k-ab-a2b2-ab-if-a-b-1-then-k-1-or-k-3

Comment: For (2) see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649433/suppose-a-b-1-then-2ab-a2b-1-text-or-3

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = a + b$ and $v = a - b$. Clearly $u$ and $v$ are both odd or both even.
 Express $a$ and $b$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

$\gcd(m,n) = g$ if and only if g is the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as $\alpha m + \beta n = g$

So there exists integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha a + \beta b = 1$ Change that into an expression involving $u$ and $v$ and go from there.